# Generating line-graphs in Java for .xls files

Tags: java, excel

Are there any libraries out there that can be used to generate line-graphs and export them to a .xls file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Apache POI (http://poi.apache.org/). However you need to use a limited workaround for this to work.

"You can not [sic] currently create charts. You can however create a chart in Excel, modify the chart data values using HSSF and write a new spreadsheet out. This is possible because POI attempts to keep existing records intact as far as possible." (http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/limitations.html)

You could also look into using the JExcelAPI (http://sourceforge.net/projects/jexcelapi/), but  I have no familiarity with its limitations.

Comment: I get the idea that there aren't really any good libraries for .xls files and Java.

Comment: Yeah. Java is somewhat limited in that regard. You may want to go with Python.